# ExtJS 4 - How to persist values of textfields in a floating panel when panel is hidden/shown?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am building an ExtJS4 Web Application and there's a part where the user is shown a "Search Panel". It's basically a floating panel with textfields and a gridView. The textfields allow the user to put his or her input for first name and last name filters. There's also a combo box that the user can use to filter the search. The results are shown in the gridView. The search functionality works well.

However, when the floating panel is hidden and then shown, the fields are reset and the user would have to enter the input once more.

What I want to happen is for the textfield and combobox values to persist even though the panel is hidden then shown again. I have tried using `setVisibility(false)` then using `setVisibility(true)` but that did not work for me.

How can I persist values of fields when their parent view is hidden/shown?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or share some code?

Comment: ended up using cookies instead. saved the textfield values on the `beforehide` event trigger and then restored them in the `show` function with a little delay.

Comment: try to use `'stateful'` property, it should help

Answer (score 0):

The fields should have retained the value as you are just hiding and showing the search panel. It seems there is a bug in your program, but I cannot ascertain that without seeing some code. Assuming that your search panel includes a close button, I would suggest you to use `closeAction: 'hide'` on the panel instead of using `setVisibility()`. Also make sure that you are not creating multiple instances of search panel, use a single object of search panel.

Here is a quick fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DirtyParadoxx/gL9aekzz/

If you want to use cookies, then as Nikolay Lopin suggested, `stateful: true` would be a nice way of doing it.